# Patch PHP 5.3.10 to support sybase_next_result()

Tags: php, patch, sap-ase

The database management system Sybase ASE supports multiple result sets, however the implementation of Sybase in PHP doesn't. There is a bug reported on this issue and there is also a patch supplied in that report (https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48675). The patch is for version 5.2.9 and I've tried to add it to version 5.3.10. The source builds without warnings or errors, and testing the new function 'sybase_next_result()' does not yield a fatal error "Call to undefined function". This would suggest that the function is implemented, but not working as expected.

Configuration is:

```
configure --disable-isapi --enable-debug-pack --without-mssql --without-pdo-mssql --without-pi3web --with-mcrypt=static --disable-static-analyze --enable-cli --with-sybase-ct=%SYBASE%\%SYBASE_OCS%
```

There is a notice on 'sybase_query()' when there are multiple result sets saying "Sybase: Unexpected results, cancelling current in...". The first result set is retrieved. And this notice is returned even without the patch.

The number of stored procedures in the database that return multiple result sets is vast, and a 'sybase_next_result()' would be the best solution. In short, I looking for an equivalent to 'mssql_next_result()' (http://se2.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-execute.php) for Sybase in PHP 5.3.10.

Worth noting is that the other parts of the Sybase implementation is in place and seems work as expected.

My testing environment is a WAMP server (Windows 7, Apache 2.21, MySQL 5.5.20, PHP 5.3.10) and Sybase ASE is version 15.7.0.

Is there anyone out there that has "solved" this?

With regards
//Jonas

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

A colleague gave me the instructions to use 'OutputDebugString()' (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362(v=vs.85).aspx) and catch that with DebugView (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647).

From this I can say that 'sybase_next_result()' is called but the block

```
if (sybase_ptr->active_result_index) {
    ...
}
```

is not run. This is probably correct (as I see it).

The row

```
retcode = ct_results(sybase_ptr->cmd, &restype);
```

is always setting 'retcode' to 'CS_FAIL'. This is perhaps because the earlier

```
ZEND_FETCH_RESOURCE2(sybase_ptr, sybase_link *, sybase_link_index, id, "Sybase-Link", le_link, le_plink);
```

sets 'sybase_ptr' in sutch fashion that 'retcode' becomes 'CS_FAIL'.

Comment: I'm unable to solve this. Anyone out there that have been successful in patching PHP to hold a working function for 'sybase_next_result()? I hope this functionality will be incorporated in coming PHP releases.